# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: "Foo" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, core-data

Ok so this is the error I'm getting

```
   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '"Place" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject.'
```

I assume that what it means is that 'Place' hasn't been added as an entity to the core data model??? But it has as shown by the image below.

I'm guessing that my assumption is incorrect though so any help or ideas would be nice.

[image]

I'm pretty certain that this is the line that's causing it:

```
  NSManagedObject* place = [NSEntityDescription
                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Place" 
                               inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Comment: Is `context` valid when you execute that line?  (Non-nil, has a connection to the persistent store coordinator....)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you aren't using custom classes (no Place.[hm]), as it sounds like you're not, check the **Entity** tab, and make sure the **Class** name is blank (= **NSManagedObject**) – not **Place**.

Comment: Champion! I don't remember touching that. What would have caused it to change?

Comment: My guess is that a subclass for the entity is actually the default.

Comment: Yah buddy! This did the trick, thanks!  This can happen if you decide to create an NSManagedObject subclass from the Editor menu.

Comment: Thank you!!! I've been struggling with this error with using `MTLManagedObjectAdapter`. I used the NSManagedObject subclass file generator in Xcode and it auto adds the Entity Class for me, then I changed the class in .h from `NSManagedObject` to `MTLModel` and didn't remove this Class setting.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem with classes called Message and Connection. The error just appeared after adding an emailing facility using the MessageUI library. I believe the conflict occurs because the library will have classes named Message and Connection, therefore they are not seen to be subclasses of NSManagedObject. Changing their names by prefixing (in my case with an X) makes the entities unique. I intend prefixing all my entities in future so that there is less chance of the conflict arising.

Comment: Doh, good find. Had an entity named Message that was throwing this fatal.

Comment: I literally had the exact same problem, with a class named 'Connection'. Prefixing the name worked great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do when you encounter this kind of errors is to verify the class name of your entity :

- Open XCDataModel
- Select your entity
- Open the right pane Utilities
- Click on "show the data model inspector" button
- Verify the class name so that it's in sync with your generated model

Hope this helps !

Answer (score -1):

The other way to address this issue is to indeed use the `NSManagedObject` subclass (recommended).

```
Place *place = [NSEntityDescription
                           insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Place" 
                           inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Comment: Making Place a subclass of NSManagedObject would require a different approach than this. Changing the type of the variable won't affect the class of the object.

Comment: No it would not. As has been pointed out, it is the default and therefore recommended. It is, for instance, much safer using explicit attribute names than accessing attributes via key-value coding.